# MVC 4 - View Scaffolding Create Options

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, scaffolding

I am very new to MVC 4. When I create a new controller and select the Scaffolding option where CRUD actions are created using EF, the Create view it creates places the labels and edit fields in a single vertical column, with labels on top of the edit controls. Is there a way I can tell the Scaffolding feature to create my View in a different way? For example, I might want two columns. The first column would be the label and the second column would be its corresponding edit control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen [Scott Hanselman's post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx) on this? I believe this is what you are looking for.